# .xsession file to open chromium-browser only

Tags: 16.04, xorg, kiosk

My machine is an Ubuntu 16.04 Server running on a thin client.
These machines are meant to act as an rdp connection to servers where employees will do other work

What is the format of an .xsession file? I would like to create one and place inside directory /home/user

This file should launch chromium-browser after startx is executed.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The .xsession file is a simple shell-script.
**.xinitrc:**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

May be, you needs special arguments (fullscreen mode, url to open etc.)

See `man chromium-browser`.
There will be no window-decorations, because no window-manager is running.